# Painting on a JFrame works, but it throws NullPointerException anyway

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jframe, paint

The window shows up and works as intended, but it still gives me a NullPointerException for some reason. Two in fact. Here's the code:

```
public class SwagFrame extends JFrame {

  public SwagFrame() {super("Swag");}

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
      Image bg = null;

      try {
        bg = ImageIO.read(new File("swag.png"));
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Swag not turned on");
        System.exit(-1);
      }

      g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, null); // exception here
      g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
      g.fillOval(250, 250, 100, 100);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwagFrame frame = new SwagFrame();

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(525, 525);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.paint(null); // exception here
  }
}
```

If `paint()` requires an object in its parameters, why does it still work anyway but throw the exception after the fact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things I did. I made the SwagFrame a JPanel instead of a JFrame, so I could use the `paintComponent` method, I deleted the `frame.paint(null)` and I changed the `null` in the `drawImage` to `this`. The code works fine now.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SwagFrame extends JPanel {
    public SwagFrame() {
        
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        BufferedImage bg = null;

        try {
            bg = ImageIO.read(new File("icons/stacko/stackoverflow1.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Swag not turned on");
            //System.exit(-1);
        }

      
        g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, this); // exception here
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillOval(250, 250, 100, 100);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new SwagFrame());
        frame.setSize(525, 525);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //frame.paint(g); // exception here
    }
}
```

Also if you want to set the size of the image, you can pass it as argument to the .drawImage() method

```
g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, width, height, this);
```

And one more thing, make sure the image is in the right file location.

As @MadProgrammer stated in his comments:

> " Generally, top level containers aren't double buffered, where as Swing components (extending from JComponent) are. Top level containers have a number of layers placed ontop of them (layered pane, content pane and glass pane), making it very complex surface to safely paint to. Also, generally, when a child component is painted, the parent container doesn't need to be this can lead to dirty paints occurring. Also, generally, extending from JFrame is discouraged as you are never actually adding any additional functionality to it
>
> The reason the OPs code didn't work (as you seem to have duduced) was they were passing a null value to the paint method, when means when they tried to access "g", it threw a NPE, however, the the Repaint Manager schedule it's paint request, the paint method was passed a valid Graphics refernce, meaning it was able to work properly...also, the OP isn't call super.paint, bad on them" - @MadProgrammer

Comment: That's a good answer +1. A bit more of an explanation of why you choose to make the changes you did would make it an excellent answer ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer you know to be completely honest, I can explain about the `null` part, but I'm not really sure about the JFrame to JPanel part. I just tested OP's post and I removed the `null`s but the image still would not appear. So I changed it to a JPAnel and use `paintComponent` and the Image appeared. I'm honestly not sure why, I just know it worked. Would you like to clarify this. I will surely update my answer afterwards.

Comment: Okay, that's good honesty ;) - Generally, top level containers aren't double buffered, where as Swing components (extending from JComponent) are. Top level containers have a number of layers placed ontop of them (layered pane, content pane and glass pane), making it very complex surface to safely paint to. Also, generally, when a child component is painted, the parent container doesn't need to be  this can lead to dirty paints occurring. Also, generally, extending from JFrame is discouraged as you are never actually adding any additional functionality to it

Comment: The reason the OPs code didn't work (as you seem to have duduced) was they were passing a null value to the paint method, when means when they tried to access "g", it threw a NPE, however, the the Repaint Manager schedule it's paint request, the paint method was passed a valid Graphics refernce, meaning it was able to work properly...also, the OP isn't call super.paint, bad on them ;)